# apache commons http client efficiency

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I use apache commons http client to send data via post every second, is there a way to make the following code more efficient?  I know http is stateless, but is there anything I can do to improve since the base url is always the same in this case(only the parameter value change.

```
private void sendData(String s){ 
      try
         {
              HttpClient client = getHttpClient();


              HttpPost method = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.100:8080/myapp");
              System.err.println("send to server "+s);
              List formparams = new ArrayList();
              formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("packet", s));

              UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
              method.setEntity(entity);

              HttpResponse resp=client.execute(method);
              String res = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
              System.out.println(res);

         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
              e.printStackTrace();

         }
    }
 private HttpClient getHttpClient() {
  if(httpClient==null){
   httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  }
  return httpClient;
 }
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Do you have reason to think otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a multi-threaded connection manager,

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/threading.html#MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager

This will improve the keep-alive and improve the chance that your connection is ready every second so you don't have to reestablish the TCP connection.

Comment: nice pointer, I might not be able to use this class since I'm running on android SDK which supports limited version of apache commons http client.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send a request and get a response each second, then yeah, that's about all you can do.  However, yes, it will use a fair amount of resources.

Another approach to look into is the [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) approach, in which an HTTP connection is left open to the server and information is gradually sent over that connection.  [Here's an interesting article with examples.](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2008/jw-03-asynchhttp.html)

Comment: One HTTP request per second is nothing - it hardly justifies Comet, IMO.

Comment: The user wouldn't have asked if he/she wasn't concerned.  Better to know what the options are.